# Python - How to map and append list entries to dictionary dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary

I've spent a good part of today wrestling with this one -- I'm reading data from a serial-port server device (via socket module). Data is coming in OK, and I'm trying to do simple string processing on it (confirm correct data chunk size) prior to adding a timestamp and putting the complete chunks into a dictionary, with the timestamp as the key. Here is the code:

```
for i in range(0, (len(rawData)+1)):
    if len(rawData[i]) == 57:
        ss2000_data[str(time.time())] = (rawData[i].split(', '))
        print ss2000_data
    else: continue
```

The dictionary processing is going OK, in that I get a valid key:value pair -- once! The loop part is not working, so no matter how much serial data I receive, I'll only get a single key:value pair.

I've scanned questions here, also at the Python.org forum, and have also gone through the docs "Learning Python", "Python Pocket Ref"  and the Python Tutorial at python.org, but I'm not getting anywhere. I'm a relative noob at Python, as well. I'd appreciate any suggestions or pointers to a potential source of information.
Thanks in advance, much appreciated

Comment: Your dictionary only gets one entry, but what about those `print ss2000_data` statements? Are you seeing more than one of those?

Comment: `else: continue`? Looks a little unnecessary.

Comment: @azhrei: No, I only get 1 entry printed

Comment: @Joel Cornett: Absolutely unnecessary, in this case I wanted to ensure I had a closed block of code... it was to elimiate a dumb potential source of error, or so I thought

Comment: Everything else aside, you don't need to specify 0 as the starting value, as `range()` starts at 0 by default, and by specifying the end value as `len(rawData)+1` rather than just `len(rawData)`, you'll end up with an out-of-bounds index into your `rawData` object in the final iteration. (Unless your `rawData` object returns one less than the count of the items in it as the length for some reason.) Of course, the most Pythonic way of doing it is to use the `for... in` statement, as used in azhrei's answer.

Comment: @JAB: As I was wrestling with this piece of code, I kept "adding in" stuff to ensure I wasn't committing a simple indenting/ usage error - this was why I added in the "else: continue" stuff, the explicit starting value in the range parameter, etc. The "Len...)+1" came from my interpretation of the range discussion in the Python Pocket Ref -- the stop argument actually calculates at "Stop-1", but I wanted to go through all the items listed. Is my interpretation incorrect?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. The issue is that the maximum index of `rawData`, if `rawData` follows the standard Python indexing scheme, would be `len(rawData)-1`, not `len(rawData)`.

Comment: @JAB: Thanks, I substituted 'len(rawData)-1' as you suggested and code operated correctly.

Comment: Doing that will cause the final string in `rawData` to not be parsed. Really, you should just use azhrei's example; it's more Pythonic.

Comment: @JAB: In the code block I actually incorporated, I moved away from using a "for..." structure at all. I reduced the number of bytes I pull in, use strip() and len() to fish out the right string, then returned that, avoiding the need to iterate at all. Had I chosen to iterate, I was going to use azhrei's code snippet.  Thanks for your followup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will assume that rawData contains some lines / datagrams from a serial connection.)

`time.time()` is not guaranteed to provide fractions of a second. You may be processing too quickly for `time.time()` to provide anything other than its initial value. Try prepending `str(i)` to the key you're using to store your split data, or using another key (possibly derived from `i`) that is guaranteed to change with each loop.

Comment: the str(time.time()) construct I use is intended to provide a key for a line of serial data from a process instrument. The timing data thus created is useful to timestamp the process data, plus I was comfortable this would ensure no duplicate keys. The insight into thetiming delay is very useful. I'll explore that. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think timing was going to be an issue, since in an earlier version of the code I actually added a timestamp at the beginning of each serial data string, but then I had problems stripping out the first item as a key for a dict() construct, so I went this route. I also thought I could get what I want with less code! I think I'll go back and re-visit that earlier idea.

Comment: I have restructured the code so I will only "fish out" one full block of data per call to this module, and I'll return a single dict entry with this info, avoiding the potential delay caused by the latency of this call when iterating through a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only get 1 entry printed, that means there's only 1 entry in rawData that has a length of 57, right?

Clean the code a bit, and add some debugging. Keeping it simple and close to what you have:

```
for block in rawData:
  print 'Block,len=%d' % (len(block),)
  if len(block) == 57:
     ss2000_data[str(time.time())] = (block.split(', '))
     print ss2000_data
```

If you're expecting more than 1 entry in rawData that has a length of 57, then are you sure "data is coming in OK"?

Comment: Hey, Azhrei, thanks for this. I'm sure it's working because further up in the code I do just what you've suggested... I print rawData, and I get multiple blocks of the correct length. I've got to re-visit this code to check out the timing problem, but your block length print phrase above is better than what I'm doing.

Comment: Used wrong format, here is comment posted again... thanks for this. I'm sure it's working because further up in the code I do just what you've suggested... I print rawData, and I get multiple blocks of the correct length.